# ckeditor toolbar on explorer and chrome appears incorrectly

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

[image: ckeditor toolbar on explorer and chrome]

Using firefox, the toolbar appears as expected, not on chrome or internet explorer.
How do I fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your browser cache.
2. Check the console for any errors.
3. Check your website for conflicting CSS styles.
4. If you are using any third-party plugins, try one of the official presets (Basic, Standard, Full) and make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: 1. cleared    2. no errors   3. possible, as the form is in a div container.  any way to disable and reset css for the form?  Also no problems in firefox or ie/safari in firefox emulation.    4. using latest version.    thanks